# Best way to convert an array of integers to a vector? in java

Tags: java, arrays, vector

I have an array like

```
int [] nums={1,2,3,1,1,3};
```

So i wanted it convert it into an vector
I did try

```
Vector<Integer> num= new Vector<Integer>(Arrays.asList(nums));
```

and got this error

```
java: method addAll in class java.util.Collections cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.util.Collection<? super T>,T[]
  found:    java.util.Vector<java.lang.Integer>,int[]
  reason: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
```

Is there a way to change the types or a faster method than this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NB: Before I answer the question, Vector is deprecated and should *never* be used.  You're looking for `List`. Whatever property Vector has that makes you think you need it, I really doubt it.

The problem here is that `List` (and `Vector`) are generified, and generics **cannot be a primitive type**. So, `int[]` and `Integer[]` aren't the same thing, and for the same reason, you can't casually turn an `int[]` into a `List<Integer>`. Instead, `Arrays.asList(someIntArray)` gives you a list with **only one element in it**, and that list is of type `List<int[]>` - in other words, `nums` is treated as the single element of a list of int arrays.

There is no method in the `java.*` libraries that turns an `int[]` into a `List<Integer>` (or `Vector<Integer>`, naturally).

An easy-ish way to do it:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(nums).mapToObj(x -> x).toList();
```

This will first create an IntStream of your numbers. It then maps the `int` values to `Integer` values, using the identity operation which gets automatically sugared into `x -> Integer.valueOf(x)` (if you find it more readable like so, then go ahead and write it like that), and then turns the whole thing into a list. If `toList()` doesn't work - you're on java pre-16, write `.collect(Collectors.toList())` instead of `.toList()`.

If you don't like the above, a simple for loop would then do the job. This works just as well:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int n : nums) list.add(n);
```

Comment: Don't you mean `IntStream.of(nums)`? Also, `boxed()` is perhaps better than `.mapToObj`.

Comment: While there are very few valid reasons to use Vector, it is not deprecated.  Probably because other Java SE classes (unfortunately) rely on it, like DefaultTableModel.

Comment: @AndyTurner The [`Arrays.stream( int[] )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#stream(int%5B%5D)) method produces an `IntStream`, so is equivalent to your suggestion. I do prefer your approach, as it makes the intention more explicit: `List < Integer > integers = IntStream.of( nums ).boxed().toList();`

Comment: So this worked out for me but if you say that vectors are deprecated or shouldn't be used which is the optimal way to create a collection of items let it be int or strings ?.

Comment: `ArrayList` is the replacement.

Comment: @VGR it is deprecated. In the sense of what your dictionary says that means. It is not marked `@Deprecated`. The two concepts mostly overlap, but not entirely.